# Saving data from a Rivets.js objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, rivets.js

How can I export the data in the object that's bind to rivets view?

When I try to send the whole object (including rivets getters and setters and other methods I created) with a jQuery AJAX, my browser just crashes.

Maybe there is a JavaScript or jQuery function that allows me extract only the data from an object without its methods?

I really need a way of doing this without manually creating a data object to send.

Comment: Have you tried stringifying your object? `var data = JSON.stringify(rivets_obj)`. Now `data` contains a JSON of only the data in `rivets_obj`, without the methods.

Comment: rivets_obj has some additional properties, how can we get json data only

Answer (score 0):

Solution: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(bindedObject))`